# Bing delisted site after Cloudflare Crawler Hints sent junk URLs to Bing via IndexNow

Tags: search-engine-indexing, cloudflare, bing

I found my site delisted by Bing after many years of being the top result for my search terms. This site is part of a WordPress network and the 100 or so other sites are unaffected.

The only point of difference between the other sites and this was that I noticed Bing’s index of the site contained hundreds of junk URLs that do not exist, and never have. The following were all submitted through Crawler Hints to Bing.

[image: Junk exploit scans included in Bing's index of my site sent from Cloudflare via IndexNow]

So what’s happening is a bad actor is running exploit scans on the domain looking for compromised URLs. None of those exist so they cause a cache miss at Cloudflare, and Crawler Hints then submits this to Bing via IndexNow.

I've reached out to Cloudflare to find out what point in their flow Crawler Hints works. If it was after WAF/bot management then it shouldn't send these URLs as they are not legitimate traffic.

I've also sent tickets into the black hole of Bing support and haven't heard back.

Any ideas how to get this site showing on Bing again?

Comment: Are you sure that these junk URLs were never used by malware that infected your website? It is very common for malware to create lots of junk URLs on a WordPress website and then only show their content to search engine bots and visitors referred by search engines.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% certain that these junk URLs were never active and never resulted in anything other than a 40x.